# Where in the backend can I get information about the current WordPress version I am using?

Tags: updates, wordpress-version

In the dashboard backend admin area, I only see `Update to Wordpress <Latest Version>` in the updates section, and at the bottom, is the `Get Version <Latest Version>` link, but nowhere does it tell me what version of Wordpress I am using in the backend anywhere, before deciding to update to the latest version.

Where can I get this information?

Comment: I really do understand your frustration (as I share it). "view the source of the page on the front-end in order to see the version of Wordpress" this sounds bad, you shouldn't leak the WP version like this. Besides that, what do you expect from this question? WordPress StackExchange is not for discussion and I don't see a question that can be objectively answered in your text.

Comment: On my dashboard page, I see `Version 5.7.1` at the right bottom corner)

Comment: @anton If you're not on 5.7.1 it will just display something like "Update to 5.7.1" without displaying the current version.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's not right in front of you, but you can obtain this information from the back end.

Go to
`Tools -> Site Health -> Click on Info tab.`

Clicking on the first drop-down ('Wordpress') will get you the current version and the latest.

Comment: Thanks, so there it is... Just would be nice if it were listed where you update wordpress at exactly.  I mean, this is very frustrating not being able to see what you will be updating from exactly on the updates page.

Answer (score 1):

In `functions.php` of your child theme, insert the following code:

```
if(is_admin()) {
    function wpse_version_check() {
        global $wp_version;
        echo '<div>Current version of WordPress is <strong>' . $wp_version . '</strong></div>';
    }     
    
    function wpse_add_dashboard_widgets() {
        wp_add_dashboard_widget(
            'wp_version',
            'WP Version',
            'wpse_version_check'
        );  
    }
    add_action('wp_dashboard_setup', 'wpse_add_dashboard_widgets');
}
```

This will create dashboard widget `WP Version`.

Comment: You'll need it, if, for some reason, `At a Glance` dashboard widget is not available.